# Gerrit WEB UI connections are short

Tags: git, web, caching, config, gerrit

I would like to know if there is any option to control the web UI Gerrit sessions.
The default is 30 mins and I would like to change it to ~10 hours session.
If anybody is familiar with such configuration / anything related (maybe on gerrit.config) that would be helpful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the default is 12h. You can change this setting the following in the GERRIT-SITE/etc/gerrit.config file:

```
[cache "web_sessions"]
    maxAge=10h
```

See more information in Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html).

Comment: Actually this param is already with value of 1 week and yet I am getting some disconnections (for some of the users) after 30 mins / 2h. Depends on the user (couldn't put exactly my finger on who is getting disconnected when)